# My site fails to do content negotiation with Googlebot using the Accept-Language header

Tags: seo, google, googlebot, http, internationalization

HTTP offers [Content Negotiation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.4) (by reacting on the [Accept-Language](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3.5) request header) to deliver translated representations of a resource under one URI. In [January 2015](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/01/crawling-and-indexing-of-locale.html) Google finally implemented this feature and calls it ["Locale-aware crawling by Googlebot"](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6144055).

Could anybody get different representations under one URI successfully into the index?

I'm trying this for http://www.mixcloud-downloader.com/ which can additionally to its default English representation serve a German representation. This site is since one month in Google's index. Additionally to the `Vary: accept-language` response header, I also added an indication which languages are supported:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://www.mixcloud-downloader.com/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="http://www.mixcloud-downloader.com/" />
```

If I would search for something from the German representation which is unique in the internet (e.g. [`"Mixcloud Internetadresse"`](https://www.google.de/webhp?hl=de#hl=de&q=%22Mixcloud+Internetadresse%22) with quotes) google.de doesn't find it.

What do I have to do, to make Google successfully aware of a translated representation under one URI?

**Edit:** I noticed that my application was sending a bogus `Content-Language` header, which might have confused Google. I fixed that on 2017-01-19. Previously it did respond with e.g. a zh-CN header and English content (if the client requested zh-CN).

Comment: The code looks correct, how have you created the sitemap.xml?

Comment: There's no sitemap.xml. Also from [this document](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156184) I don't see a reason how a sitemap might help.

Comment: The Accept-Language header is notoriously unreliable.   Non-English users regularly use English browsers because they are the easiest to download.   Not to mention problems using somebody's computer when traveling.   The header should at best be taken as an indication that the user is in the wrong place with something on page to let them switch.   It should not be used as the sole determinant of the language of the page.  I recommend sticking with something in the URL to indicate language.

Comment: When you searched for the German text did you have your Accept-Language header set to "de"?  I wouldn't expect Google to return results to you that you couldn't actually get to without the proper settings.

Comment: Yes I did set my client's header to "de". And guess what, now Google finds this question as the only result when searching for [`"Mixcloud Internetadresse"`](https://www.google.de/webhp?hl=de#hl=de&q=%22Mixcloud+Internetadresse%22). That was fast.

Comment: I didn’t look into it, but I guess that it’s not a good idea to use `hreflang`+`alternate` in this case. That’s the way you should use if you have different URLs, but not if you use the same URL with content negotiation.

Comment: @unor Do you have a reference for that? I though that is a good idea, so that Googlebot knows which languages it should try. Otherwise how else would Googlebot know which languages are available?

Comment: @JessyJames: Google only says that the Googlebot "uses a variety of signals", without describing which. But if they would support `hreflang`+`alternate` for this case, they would certainly document it there (… I hope, at least). Instead, they refer to it only for the recommended alternative of using different URLs. Also, from the perspective of HTML, it wouldn’t make sense to use the `alternate` link type and link to the same URL, as you can’t convey in HTML that a different `Accept-Language` request should be made by the client.

Comment: Thank you guys, for your input so far. Unfortunately I still don't know how to negotiate with Google, nor do I see any living example. Therefore I created [test cases](http://negotiate.mixcloud-downloader.com/) in the hope to find some day one of the case's translation in the index. Feel free to comment on that or suggest further scenarios.

Comment: I have the exact same problem on our site www.rowshare.com. What is "a variety of signals" ?? Ripping my hair for months. The irony is google's own https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6144055 page works exactly like that! Its content varies according to your browser language settings, or you can add a hr=language like hr=fr, hr=de to force a specific one. Guess what, there's not hreflang in it, only a rel=canonical... I've noticed this page sends an unknown "server=content-support-ui" HTTP header. Maybe you can test this, as I can't right now?

Comment: Thanks I'll add that to my tests. I'm also hair ripping land. None of the scenarios was indexed so far.

Answer (score 1):

In the Google's documentation you rely Google mentions to recommend to use separate URLs for each language version, considering sensitivity and error vulnerability of local adaptive setup.

Further, in [this](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192) documentation, Google mentions

> You can help Google determine the language correctly by using a **single
>   language for content and navigation on each page** 
>   ... 
>   **Keep the content for each language on separate URLs**

If you stay with it come hell, you should rely on both of Accept Language AND geolocation to point visitors and Googlebot to correct language version. Because your troubles begin not with Accept-Language, but with its absence.

Googlebot comes not often with defined locale parameter, and you can't constrain it. If so, visitors of your site like Googlebot, without Accept-Language, get, as now, only english content served, not dependently of their location.

You should enrich your setup with the second check routine, for the visitor's location, somehow like this:

```
- visitor comes
- check 1: Accept-Language yes/no? If yes - serve matching content, if no:
- check 2: geolocate visitors IP-address.
           If Germany/Austria/Swiss- serve german, if another country - server english.
```

But even with this setup you will be never sure and can never actively influence that Google indexes content in all languages. The most possible variant would be, that Google gets english content to 100%, and german... my bet for best case - 30%.

Your site has a handful of pages - make just unique URLs for each language and you haven't this headache.

**PS**: On answering your question found a cool tool for checking exactly the question's subject: https://technicalseo.com/seo-tools/locale-adaptive/.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion. I'm aware on Googles recommendation. However Google states it does use the `Accept-Language` for crawling. My questions are "Is there any existing site which does Content negotiation and got into the index" to ultimately answer "What does my site wrong". I don't see how you answer any of this.

Comment: I'm currently evaluating your recommended tool. Interestingly it states "Vary:Accept-Language No", which is not the truth. Not so cool that tool.